# adding random noise for sending few Mbyte data using netem

Tags: networking, jitter

I am sending a 30Mbyte file from one machine to another(both raspi 4) using scp. I tried to add noise to the network using netem on the client.

```
sudo tc qdisc change dev wlan0 root netem delay 50ms 30ms distribution normal
```

and it takes 07:17 minutes (or rate of 70.6KB/s)

However, when I increase the mean of the added noise normal distribution using

```
sudo tc qdisc change dev wlan0 root netem delay 500ms 30ms distribution normal
```

it only takes 00:33 minutes (or rate of 920.1KB/s). Logically it has to take at least the same time as the former distribution, however, it is way faster. I repeated it multiple times, and I got the same result.

I was wondering if I am using the tc in a correct way.